# Open link with custom url encoding for React Native on ios

Tags: react-native

How would one implement custom url encoding for React Native's Linking API for IOS?

I am using React-Native's Linking API to allow users to open simple http/https hyperlinks within my app using the basic example from the documentation:

```
Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
  if (supported) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
  } else {
    console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + url);
  }
});
```

On Android, the url being passed into `Linking.openURL(url);` is the same as what shows up in the browser bar when the link is opened. However, on IOS, the url is being encoded. Readability of the url aside, the main problem I'm having is the conversion of the hash character '#' to '%23' which is causing the link to not work properly. I would like to either move responsibility for url encoding to the React Native code prior to calling `Linking.openURL();` or at least make an exception for the '#' character.

Comment: I addressed this by editing the RTCLinkingManager.m file in the Libraries folder of my xcode project. I modified the function that reads RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openURL ... 

to substitute the instance of NSURL passed in with one where I replace %23 with the '#' I needed for the links to function as intended.

Comment: After two years this is still an issue. Thanks for you comment, helped me to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: I'm encountering this issue. Does anyone have a link to a react native bug ticket?

Comment: I opened a new issue for this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28508